# N-body simulation in C++ has great momentum conservation and huge energy deviation

Tags: c++, precision, game-physics, numerical-methods, verlet-integration

I am using Verlet integration (more specifically, the last equation in the "[Non-constant time differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Non-constant_time_differences)" section in the Verlet integration Wikipedia page), with C++ and the Eigen library, to create a numerical N-body simulation.

I've tried measuring the momentum and energy conservation of the simulation. For momentum conservation, even for systems where objects get very close and fast, I've gotten about 10^(-7)% deviation from the initially calculated momentum. As for the energy, I've seen it jump all the way to 800%. It starts off low, about 0.0001%, but gets much much bigger as the simulation goes on, and reaches up to 100%+ when objects are very close.

(to clarify, by deviation, I mean (y/x) - 1, where y is the current value and x is the initial.)

It seems very, very strange that my program conserves momentum so well, yet energy is completely off.

According to what I read on Meta StackOverflow, it's not recommended to post large chunks of code. I've included here the bare essentials of what I'm doing (Verlet integration implementation, gravitational force calculation). [Here](https://github.com/Proxagonal/Minimal.git) is a Github repo of a minimal reproducible example if anyone wants to look into the finer details.

```
    void verletNextStep(double dt) {

        // as per wikipedia
        if (!firstStepDone) {
            lastPosition = position;
            position = lastPosition
                       + velocity * dt
                       + 0.5 * acceleration * dt * dt;
            lastDt = dt;
            firstStepDone = true;
            return;
        }

        Vector2<long double> nextPosition = position
                                + (position - lastPosition) * dt/lastDt
                                + acceleration * dt * (dt + lastDt)/2;
        lastDt = dt;

        lastPosition = position;
        position = nextPosition;

        velocity = (position - lastPosition)/dt;

    };
```

```
    Vector2<long double> totalGravitationalAccelerationOf(Body &body) {

        Vector2<long double> acc(0, 0);

        for (Body &otherBody : bodyList)
            if (body.vectorTo(otherBody).norm() != 0)
                acc += gravitationalAccelerationOf(body, otherBody);

        return acc;
    };

    //acceleration exerted by body2, on body1
    Vector2<long double> gravitationalAccelerationOf(Body &body1, Body &body2) {

        Vector2<long double> rHat = body1.vectorTo(body2).normalized();
        long double rSquared = body1.vectorTo(body2).squaredNorm();

        return rHat * G * body2.mass/rSquared;
    };

    //executes verlet integration on all bodies
    void doVerlet(double dt) {

        for (Body &body : bodyList)
            body.acceleration = totalGravitationalAccelerationOf(body);


        for (Body &body : bodyList)
            body.verletNextStep(dt);

    }
```

I had reason to suspect the inaccuracy was due to overflow of doubles. I changed everything to long doubles, and tested on systems that had much lower energies, yet the deviation still persists.
In addition, another post presents a similar problem, but the solution in their case was orderly computation of acceleration (without updating bodies in-between), which I have implemented, as can be seen in the above code.

Comment: `(position - lastPosition) * dt/lastDt` , shouldn't that be `velocity * dt`? I mean your `velocity` variable is unused

Comment: I suppose you can write it like that, but since velocity isn't a part of the Verlet formula originally, I preferred to just use the regular version.

Comment: I know very little about N-body, the most is that it's a chaos system, with great increases of numeric inaccuracy.

Comment: If double and long double give very similar results, then it is not rounding errors, but what your formulas are actually calculating.

Comment: Usually you would take location and velocity as two variables with pos’ = vel and vel’ = acceleration and run both through the solver. You lose all the precision gains of your solver.

Comment: @Ripi2 Indeed, but this type of inaccuracy is very strange to me. The momentum is kept so well, yet the energy is wild.

Comment: @gnasher729 Pardon, but I'm not really sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Oh shit. Just looked up Verlet. I thought you used some primitive method for the velocity but Verlet just _is_ that primitive. Do yourself a favour and lookup Runge-Kutta or Runge-Kutta Fehlberg if you want any useful results.

Comment: Momentum is easily conserved because the momentum gain of one body is the momentum loss of another and your forces are guaranteed to be equal and opposite. Show us how you computed energy (kinetic+potential).

Comment: @gnasher729 I've heard from multiple sources that Verlet should be quite decent at conserving energy. I'm aware that RK4 is best, but I just want to try Verlet for now.

Comment: @lastchance I see. My code is in the linked github repo: potential energy computation starts at line 46 of Solver.h, and kinetic energy is calculated per body with the "kineticEnergy()" function defined in Body.h, then summed up in main.

Comment: ISTR there is a mistake you can make in that method that will more or less conserve energy at the expense of slightly worse conservation of momentum. Published about 1984 but I can't recall the journal. Serious codes for this problem now use symplectic integration see [Symplectic Integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator). Even RK4 won't cut it. Serious players used to soften the force law for close encounters to avoid things blowing up. Some good but now rather old stuff on [Sverre Aarseth's] (https://people.ast.cam.ac.uk/~sverre/web/pages/nbody.htm) page

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: I heard from multiple sources that Verlet is absolutely primitive. Euler is about the same. Heun is a massive improvement. Runge-Kutta is a massive improvement on that. Fehlberg is better again, and also gives a very good estimate for the error in Runge-Kutta, so you can adjust your step size. You preserve the energy by calculating position and  speed correctly. Just solve s’ = c and c’ = -s (correct result is sine and cosine) and look at the errors.

Comment: One issue is that kinetic energy is large positive and potential energy is large negative. The TOTAL energy may then be quite close to 0, and you are using that to normalise your “deviation”. A second issue is that you are operating with variables of astronomically (sorry!) different magnitudes, which causes problems of itself. Non-dimensionalise your system so that the physical variables are order one. A remote third possibility is that your bodies could crash into each other.

Comment: I tried running your code with more sub intervals (effectively a smaller time step). It didn’t remove the problems, so I don’t think that a high order scheme would do better. I think that there are just points where your bodies get very close and move very fast: a variable time step makes sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the potential each interaction is only contained once in the potential energy. At the moment you compute the interaction as double iteration over the full list of bodies, so that the interaction potential for each pair is computed twice. So either correct that in the computation or divide the result by two.

---

By the way, IMO the whole idea of variable time steps with Verlet is bunk. The quasi-energy preservation property critically depends on the time step being fixed, the ersatz energy that is nearly constant has a perturbation term that depends on the step size. With a different step size you get a different ersatz energy that is kept constant, so the first ersatz energy can change. During periodic changes from smaller to larger step sizes and back these energy discrepancies can accumulate

Momentum behaves a little bit better as symplectic method steps preserve linear and quadratic expressions in the state variable exactly.

With n-body simulations you can usually not avoid that the bodies get close to near collisions, at these times even the fixed-step Verlet breaks down, as the perturbation terms of the ersatz energy have a worse singularity than the energy function itself, usually one gets non-sensical explosions out of the system.

One gets similar divergences for two-body problems with high eccentricity, that is, very elliptical, non-circular orbits.

Comment: I've tried to search "ersatz energy" on google, but nothing comes up.
In any case, my minimal reproducible example (shown in Github link) uses a fixed time step, yet still does not preserve energy. It also (according to my visualization using sfml) doesn't have the bodies come very close.

Would this be fixed using RK4?

Comment: That was just me being German and having fun with "ersatz" and "ansatz" being proper English words. Look for the Hairer papers and books on geometric integration, there they discuss how to find the perturbation of the Hamiltonian that is constant along the numerical solution.

Comment: I see. I'm not a native English speaker, so I wasn't aware "ersatz" was a real word, haha.
I've tried reading the paper, and while most of it is beyond me, the part that stuck out to me was figure 3.1, where they show that Verlet integration has a periodic deviation from the hamiltonian, and no drift. That contrasts with my simulation. I've also looked at one of your other answers, where you mention that pertubations have order O(h^2) "with correct initialization", which is not my case. Again, in my MRE, the step size is small and uniform, h=0.001. So why does the huge deviation persist?

Comment: You are counting the potential energy twice. That reduce some of the observed effect, but possibly not all of it.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have done it. The energy conservation is now better than momentum, and with the Ruth 4 algorithm (which I implemented to try to debug the issue), it's at about 10^-17.